# How can I parse multiple XML documents at once?

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, sax

I am using a SAXParser in Java to parse my XML documents. Now I would like to improve the performance and parse multiple documents at once.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the question.
when you say " Parsing multiple documents " you mean that you want to append them together and then parse them or what?

Comment: If you can parse *one* document then I don't think there may be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with [Concurrent Programming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Spawning different threads where each of them parses one document would realize multithreaded XML parsing. Making use [Thread Pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) would ease the implementation.